# Execute a random SQL query and get the result into datagridview

Tags: c#, mysql

I am using C# and MySQL

So far I've tried to execute SELECT, INSERT, DELETE commands and display result in datagridview using DataSet and MySqlDataAdapter successfully.

But now I want to **1.execute a random query** (whatever user type into a Textbox and press Execute button) and also **2.display result in a datagridview****.

What are these steps needed to archive that task?

(I tried to search but only return me those results in what people are using specific command like SELECT, my case is different, the query is randomly typed by user)

Comment: Since you've already tried executing select, insert, delete commands, you can pass the user's input from the textbox into the SqlCommand text

Comment: Not simple like that, since then I use ExecuteNonQuery, then display new updated database's table by dataset.Clear and adapter.Fill. But now the result is different, I dont know how to get it, for example what should I do with this query: SELECT COUNT(*) from TableName

Comment: You can just bind the result to a datagridview.

Comment: @GianAcuna Don't you mind to give me an example like few lines of code and explain what you did?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code snippet of binding a query result into a gridview:

```
DataSet objDataSet = new DataSet();
SqlConnection objConn = new SqlConnection();

SqlCommand objComm = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table", objConn);

SqlDataAdapter objDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(objComm);

if (objConn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
{
    objConn.Open();
}

objDataAdapter.Fill(objDataSet, strTable);

dataGridView1.DataSource = objDataSet;
```

Comment: hey I copied and pasted your code but nothing happened, do I have to add DataMember?

Comment: You have to establish a connection first

Comment: I made it worked, basically the INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE commands only return number of rows affected by executing the query so you not really can display anything in datagridview but you can display a messageBox show that how many row(s) has been affected, other than those commands, just use Adapter and DataSet to fill and display result in datagridview.

Comment: does my answer help your question?